# ncurses most portable keys to use

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, ncurses

I use ncurs for an application which dispays data to users in real-time.

the user can do string input of normal `char` type. e.g a-z, A-Z 0-9 etc. So I cannot use those keys to do other things like change windows or quit.

Now it seemed like a good idea to use the F-keys but some `KEY_F(x)` are not recognized on some terminal emulators.

What keys are the best to use and offer the best portability for a ncurses application?

Comment: Many programs uses `ESC` to display a menu with a list of options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I favour using one of the modifier keys with letters, it is something of a defacto standard in ncurses apps to use the letter keys with control held down for special functions.

This approach instantly gives you 26 * 2 + 9 hotkey combos for special functions, plenty for most apps.

Please take a look at gnu nano for a great example of this. Remember these may be hard to remember for new users so try and provide some kind of tool-tips or a easy to remember help button like escape or ctrl-h.

Comment: You may notice a small lag between `ESC` and functionality, as the terminal supports _multibyte escape sequences_. The value can be controlled with the environment variable `ESCDELAY`, but you may find it easier to implement `CTRL+` codes (CTRL+H) as suggested in this answer.